# Missing Keyword ORA00905

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello can you assist me? im getting error Missing keyword. 
See code bellow. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Datum, Wdomain, Lgstkproc, Username,
Case when LGSTKPROC = 'NAVUL'
         COUNT (unique username '-'palnumber end nr_pal_per_user_navul,
Case when LGSTKPROC !=‘NAVUL’
         COUNT (unique username '-'palnumber end nr_pal_per_user_veplaatst
From (
SELECT USERNAME, RES, RESTYPE, WDOMAIN, LGSTKPROC,  LOCNAME, ENDLOCNAME, PALNUMBER, TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) datum 
FROM TransportStock$VW TS
WHERE TRUNC(timestamp)<TRUNC(sysdate)-1
AND res NOT LIKE '%CONVS%'
)
Group by Username, Datum,  Lgstkproc, Wdomain
```

Comment: `CASE` syntax is: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END`

Comment: `COUNT(UNIQUE...)` should be `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

Comment: @GMB Thank you ill try to replace unique with distinct

Comment: One of the best skills as an sql developer is the art of debugging sql. You can debug invalid syntax errors by pulling out individual pieces, one at a time, until it compiles fine. That will help you identify the problematic syntax. In your particular case, there are a number of syntax errors, not just one. Try to debug it yourself and you will gain a valuable debugging skill.

Comment: @SamM Thank you I will continue trying, deadline makes it hard to be patient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma, here:

```
SELECT datum,
       wdomain,
       lgstkproc,
       username,
       COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN lgstkproc = 'NAVUL' THEN 
                                 username || '-' || palnumber
                       END) AS nr_pal_per_user_navul,                --> comma missing here
       COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN lgstkproc != 'NAVUL' THEN 
                                 username || '-' || palnumber
                       END) AS nr_pal_per_user_veplaatst
FROM (SELECT username,
             res,
             restype,
             wdomain,
             lgstkproc,
             locname,
             endlocname,
             palnumber,
             trunc(SYSDATE - 1) datum
      FROM transportstock$vw ts
      WHERE trunc(timestamp) < trunc(SYSDATE) - 1
        AND res NOT LIKE '%CONVS%'
     )
GROUP BY username,
         datum,
         lgstkproc,
         wdomain
```

Things are much more clear if you properly format code you write.

Besides, those `COUNT`s don't make much sense - both `CASE`s select the same value, regardless `lgstkproc`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```
Case when LGSTKPROC = 'NAVUL'
     COUNT (unique username '-'palnumber end nr_pal_per_user_navul,
```

I speculate that you want:

```
count(distinct case when LGSTKPROC = 'NAVUL'
                    then username || '-' || palnumber
               end) as nr_pal_per_user_navul
```

Comment: Linhof, you are absolutely right, im already line ahead, yet getting few errors, but your statement seriously helpful